# Big tiles make the floor look/looks bigger

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Big tiles make the floor *look* bigger.

Big tiles make the floor *looks* bigger.

Which one is correct? According to my logic, the second verb of this sentence would be *looks* as its subject is *the floor* which is a third person singular number. Or it would be *look* for any other reason? Please let me know with explanation.

Answer (score 5):

It is "look". This is a bare infinitive.

The relation between "make", "the floor" and "look bigger" is not a verb followed by a finite clause.  Instead the verb make is followed by an infinitive verb clause, but it is a "bare" infinitive, without "to"

So at least one parsing is that "the floor" is the object of "make" and the infintive phrase is "look bigger".  It is probably also possible to parse "the floor look bigger" as an infinitive clause with "the floor" as its subject.

Here is the parsing by [computer](https://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/link/submit-sentence-4.html):

```
(S (NP Big tiles)
   (VP make
       (NP the floor)
       (VP look
           (ADJP bigger)))
   .)
```

(It will parse the other version, but only by assuming that "looks" is the plural of a noun  "a look", which is obviously nonsensical)

Comment: Are ‘non-finite clause’ and ‘infinitive verb clause’ the same thing?

Comment: Infinitives are one type of non-finite clause, the others are gerunds and participles.